# oracle sql self-join filter in the join clause vs where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join, self-join

Suppose I have a table

```
 Table A
 ---------------
 id    date_id (yyyyMMdd format)
 ---------------
 1     20120101
 2     20120102
 3     20120103
```

What is the difference between doing:

```
 select a1.* from A a1
 left outer join A a2
     on a1.id = a2.id 
     and a1.date_id < a2.date_id
 where a1.date >= 20120103
 and a2.id is null
```

And

```
 select a1.* from A a1
 left outer join A a2
      on a1.id = a2.id
      and a1.date_id < a2.date_id
      and a1.date_id >=20120103
 where a2.id is null
```

For the first query I get

```
 id   date_id
 --------------
 3    20120103
```

As expected, but for the second one I get (a2 columns not selected in query but shown here for clarity)

```
 a1.id   a1.date_id  a2.id   a2.date_id
 ---------------------------------------
 1       20120101    
 1       20120101    
 2       20120102
 2       20120102
 3       20120103
```

Shouldn't the second query also filter by `a1.date_id >= 20120103`? Why is it returning rows with date_id's `20120101 and 20120102`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of outer join, `ON` clause will have no effect on outer table. This means that all rows from outer table will be returned and `ON` clause just determine which row of a joined table joins outer table. And those rows of outer table that do not meet condition(s) in the `ON` clause simply will be extended with null values for columns of the table that is being joined. `WHERE` clause filters the final result set.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, it will first fetch the result set of on

```
a1.id = a2.id 
     and a1.date_id < a2.date_id and then it will apply the `where clause` in the result set and so you get '20120103'.
```

In the second query you are taking all the records that satisfy

```
on a1.id = a2.id
      and a1.date_id < a2.date_id
      and a1.date_id >=20120103
```

and thats why you get those many rows. Hope this helps you.